# How to mimic Active Record association using raw SQL query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

In Rails application I have two associated (as many to many) tables — *volumes* and *tracks*.

*volumes* is a collection of radio show episodes. Each episode has multiple *tracks*. But each track can appear on many shows.

*volumes*:

```
 id  |         title
-----+-----------------------
 23  | Oldstyle
 24  | How to stop worrying
```

*tracks*:

```
  id  |        artist        |         title
------+----------------------+------------------------
 4764 | John Lennon          | Mind Games
 4765 | George Harrison      | All Those Years Ago
 4766 | Paul McCartney       | Here Today
```

What I need is to aggregate tracks by artist and show all show volumes that have that artist tracks. Something like `Artist.select(name: 'Beatles').volumes`.

The problem is I don't have *Artist* model. And don't want to create it, because I believe it will make manual data cleanup much harder.

For example, I can query data I need like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.artist, v.number
FROM tracks t
JOIN volumes_tracks vt ON vt.track_id = t.id
JOIN volumes v ON v.id = vt.volumes_id
GROUP BY artist, number;
```

But is it possible to wrap it model-like data structure for easy access?

Comment: Why not just create the Artist model?
If you're worried about performance then I guess you want to have that model. If not, then what's the harm of a few artists records in your database that never gets cleaned. (and can be cleaned quite easiliy,with  something like: `Artist.includes(:tracks).where({tracks: {id: nil}}).delete`)

Comment: Probably, you're right. The only reason I didn't want to have Artist model is because it would make manual reviewing data more complicated. Sometimes rows in Track table are broken — it has `artist: "Bob Dylan- Blowng in the Wind", track: ""`, for example. But I can overcome such trouble with slightly more complicated join query, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can map each result returned by the sql query to a Struct, which may give you the ease of access that you're looking for. Something like this:

```
   Artist = Struct.new(:artist, :volume_id)  
   result=ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
   artists = result.map{|r| Artist.new(r['t.artist'], r['v.id']}
   first_artist = artists[0].artist
```

(the sql variable represents your sql query string)